# Is it possible to use "read_holding_registers" with unitid greater than 255 in TCP mode?

Tags: pymodbus, thingsboard-gateway

I am using thingsboard gateway to connect to a modbus slave with unitid greater than 255, the pymodbus throws error like below:

```
tb-gateway-py_1    | struct.error: ubyte format requires 0 <= number <= 255
tb-gateway-py_1    | ''2020-04-23 08:43:46' - ERROR - modbus_connector - 178 - ubyte format requires 0 <= number <= 255'
tb-gateway-py_1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
tb-gateway-py_1    |   File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/thingsboard_gateway/connectors/modbus/modbus_connector.py", line 122, in __process_devices
tb-gateway-py_1    |     input_data = self.__function_to_device(current_data, unit_id)
tb-gateway-py_1    |   File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/thingsboard_gateway/connectors/modbus/modbus_connector.py", line 226, in __function_to_device
tb-gateway-py_1    |     unit=unit_id)
tb-gateway-py_1    |   File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymodbus/client/common.py", line 114, in read_holding_registers
tb-gateway-py_1    |     return self.execute(request)
tb-gateway-py_1    |   File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymodbus/client/sync.py", line 108, in execute
tb-gateway-py_1    |     return self.transaction.execute(request)
tb-gateway-py_1    |   File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymodbus/transaction.py", line 153, in execute
tb-gateway-py_1    |     broadcast=broadcast
tb-gateway-py_1    |   File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymodbus/transaction.py", line 217, in _transact
tb-gateway-py_1    |     packet = self.client.framer.buildPacket(packet)
tb-gateway-py_1    |   File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymodbus/framer/socket_framer.py", line 212, in buildPacket
tb-gateway-py_1    |     message.function_code)
tb-gateway-py_1    | struct.error: ubyte format requires 0 <= number <= 255
```

Is it possible to use "read_holding_registers" with unitid greater than 255 in TCP mode?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I end up by modifying the standard Modbus protocol between the thingsboard gateway Modbus connector and the Modbus slave. The unit id was 1 byte, which then I modified to 4 bytes. As for the devices, they can only use standard Modbus protocol, then I put a modbus slave proxy between the Modbus slave (unitid 4 bytes) and the devices. The modbus slave proxy can communicate with the Modbus slave (unitid 4 bytes).

This may not be quite good a solution, but is solves my problem.